# Persisting login states with passport.js, mysql, and express-session

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an app that uses Passport.js to authenticate users through facebook, and can do so successfully. However, whenever my node.js server is reset, the user is logged out.

It seems like express-sessions is the way to go to persist login states, but every answer I've read seems to say you must use mongodb or redis to achieve this. We are using Mysql.

Is there a way to use express-sessions with mysql to persist login states?

Answer (score 3):

You can use session (express-session) to achieve that.
I currently using this combination
express, express-session, express-mysql-session (for the storage), passport with facebook and twitter strategies. An a basic setup could be something like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var app = express();

var options = {
    host: '',// Host name for database connection.
    port: '',// Port number for database connection.
    user: '',// Database user.
    password: '',// Password for the above database user.
    database: ''// Database name
};
var connection = mysql.createConnection(options);
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({
    checkExpirationInterval: 900000,// How frequently expired sessions will be cleared; milliseconds.
    expiration: 86400000,// The maximum age of a valid session; milliseconds.
    createDatabaseTable: true,// Whether or not to create the sessions database table, if one does not already exist.
    schema: {
        tableName: 'sessions',
        columnNames: {
            session_id: 'session_id',
            expires: 'expires',
            data: 'data'
        }
    }
}, connection);

app.use(session({
    key: 'MyKey',
    secret: 'MySecret',
    cookie: {domain: '.mydomain.com', httpOnly: true, secure: false},
    domain: '.mydomain.com',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

/**
 * Session handle for passport
 */
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/**
* Check if user is authenticated in a route
*/
function authUser (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/login')
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

router.get('/hello', authUser, function(req, res){
    //Code
});


/**
 * Start the server on port defined by configuration
 */
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

More info at:

https://github.com/expressjs/session

https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have implemented the above code in my app and sessionStore is successfully talking to my mysql DB. I am still having a tough time figuring out how to use this to persist login states. I created a mysql table called "loginRequest" and this is the table I am using in the tableName property. There is something strange happening. Whenever I hit any route in my site, around 30 entries are put into the loginRequest table. Why is this?

Comment: No idea... perhaps you should check if the user is authenticated, before the user "reach" the route code.  I edit the answer with the code i use to authenticate the user in each route.

Comment: I just checked....the deserialize function in passport never gets hit. This is obviously a huge problem, and needs to be addressed before persisting login sessions